# Make arguments to prequisites

Tags: makefile, arguments

I am new to make. I have a very basic Make question and have searched in vain about it.I have different arguments to be given to different prerequisites.

```
a b:c d
        prog -i c -j d -out1 a -out2 b
```

I know that that $+ will list all preqs but how do I supply the arguments. I could retype a b c and d in the recipe and not use automatic variables at all but then typing needs to be done twice. A pattern rule could be made where a and b could be linked to c and d respectively but still how do I supply the arguments?

A Million Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try some simpler rules first:

```
a b c:
    @echo the target is $@
```

(Test this with "make a" or "make b c".)

```
a: c d
    @echo the prerequisites are $^
    @echo the first prerequisite is $<

a: c d
    @echo the second prerequisite is $(word 2,$^)
```

(Crude but effective.)

Your rule:

```
a b : c d
    prog -i c -j d -out1 a -out2 b
```

is a little odd in that it can be invoked with either target (`a` or `b`) and it will do *exactly the same thing.* This is perfectly legal, but although Make has access to the target name with `$@`, it cannot easily scan the names of targets it *isn't* trying to build. But there's a way you can reduce the redundant typing:

```
TARG_1 := a
TARG_2 := b
TARGS := $(TARG_1) $(TARG_2)

$(TARGS) : c d
    prog -i $< -j $(word 2,$^) -out1 $(TARG_1) -out2 $(TARG_2)
```